# Cappuccino Drag and Drop Error

Tags: cappuccino

I'm trying to implement drag and drop in cappuccino but keep getting an error when i drop an image on a CPView, i copied the error message from console below.

CPInvalidArgumentException: - [CPImage removeFromSuperview] unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x0051bd

I'm dragging an image from CPCollectionView which is contained inside a CPScrollView and dropping it on a CPView. I followed the example from the [ScrapBook](http://cappuccino.org/learn/tutorials/scrapbook-tutorial-2/) tutorial.

Below is the code on my CPView for dropping, this code causes the output from the console

```
- (void)performDragOperation:(CPDraggingInfo)aSender
{
    var data = [[aSender draggingPasteboard] dataForType:PhotoDragType];
    [self addSubview:[CPKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data]];
}
```

I defined my drag type in my AppController.j since my CPScrollView is defined their, don't know if this is causing the issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's in the drag and drop pasteboard is NOT the view, it's the representedObject of the collection view item. (In your case a CPImage object).

The solution here is to create a new CPImageView and add it to the drop view, then set the image of that image view to the pasteboard data (assuming it's always an image).

Comment: Thanks. Trying to place the image where it was dropped using       var imageview = [[CPImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake([aSender draggingLocation].x,[aSender draggingLocation].y,0,0)]; but it goes to a different location. Is there a better way or i should use the mouse event of the view that is dropped on. Regards